# How to include a parameter when calling a macro?

Tags: macros

In the beginning, I want to define a theorem environment **without number**, so I tried the following code:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm} 
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[]{testbox}
\declaretheorem[style=testbox,name=Theorem]{theo}
\renewcommand{\thetheo}{}    %Cancelling the number

\begin{document}
    \begin{theo}
        Content.
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

It works well. Then I tried to extend it into

```
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[]{testbox}
\newcommand{\newtestbox}[2]{
    \declaretheorem[style=testbox,name=#1]{#2}
    \renewcommand{\the#2}{}    %Error
}
\newtestbox{Theorem}{theo}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theo}
        Content.
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```

But now it seems that `\the#2` is recognized as some ill-formed counter call. How can I use it properly?
I'm sorry if the story is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numbered=no` (page 3 of thmtools manual).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[]{testbox}
\declaretheorem[
  style=testbox,
  numbered=no,
  name=Theorem,
]{theo}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
Content.
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with the (wrong) output you get without `numbered=no` but with `\renewcommand{\thetheo}{}`, namely

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can say:

```tex
\LoadClass[a4paper]{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\RequirePackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[]{testbox}
\newcommand{\newtestbox}[2]{
    \declaretheorem[style=testbox,name=#1]{#2}
    \expandafter\renewcommand\csname the#2\endcsname{}    %Error
}
\newtestbox{Theorem}{theo}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theo}
        Content.
    \end{theo}
\end{document}
```